# Is there a way to grab information off of a webpage and display it on a android app?

Tags: java, php, android, html

I want to grab some information off of a website (for example: a shopping website) and display the information on a android app. Is there anyway that I can do this? 
-Thanks

Comment: Please state to us what have you done so far.

Comment: @CaryBondoc I just have an idea so far.

Comment: Please review this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what you looking for is web crawling. But if it is a one web site you want to focus on, then you can do it using xpath expressions. However, if the website change it's design, element ids etc, the application would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

It might be the one that you need.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.